# Basic CRUD operation with composite Id (spring + hibernate)

Tags: spring, hibernate

Im trying to make a basic create operation with hibernate and spring, but i keep getting the message that a id is empty when it is not.So im thinking that it might be because, the entity uses a composite id, fun fact at least for me is that i don't have any problem deleting the entities.

**The method im using**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="addPatientFamilyRelative",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addPatientFamilyRelative(@RequestParam(value="idPatient")int idPatient,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="idRelative")int idRelative,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="idRelationship")int idRelationship)
    {
        Patient_Relative patientRelative = new Patient_Relative();
                patientRelative.setIdRelationship(relationshipService.getById(idRelationship));
                patientRelative.setPatient(patientService.getById(idPatient));
                patientRelative.setRelative(relativeService.getRelative(idRelative));


                prService.create(patientRelative);

        return "$('#tblPatientFamilyPatientRelatives').ajax.reload();$('#tblPatientRelativesList').ajax.reload()";
    }
```

**Patient_Relative class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Patient_Relative")
public class Patient_Relative implements Serializable{

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2670460334767266076L;
    @EmbeddedId
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRelative", referencedColumnName = "idRelative", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
        @JsonIgnore
    private Relative relative;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idRelationship", referencedColumnName = "idRelationship")
    @ManyToOne
    private Relationship idRelationship;
    @JoinColumn(name = "idPatient", referencedColumnName = "idPatient", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Patient patient;

    public Relative getRelative() {
        return relative;
    }
    public void setRelative(Relative relative) {
        this.relative = relative;
    }

    public Relationship getIdRelationship() {
        return idRelationship;
    }

    public void setIdRelationship(Relationship idRelationship) {
        this.idRelationship = idRelationship;
    }

    public Patient getPatient() {
        return patient;
    }
    public void setPatient(Patient patient) {
        this.patient = patient;
    }   
}
```

**PatientRelativeId**

```
@Embeddable
public class PatientRelativeId implements java.io.Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2719758608242901070L;

    @Column(name = "idPatient")
    private int patientId;

    @Column(name = "idRelative")
    private int relativeId;


    public PatientRelativeId() {
    }

    public PatientRelativeId(int patientId, int relativeId) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
        this.relativeId = relativeId;
    }

    public int getPatientId() {
        return patientId;
    }
    public void setPatientId(int patientId) {
        this.patientId = patientId;
    }
    public int getRelativeId() {
        return relativeId;
    }
    public void setRelativeId(int relativeId) {
        this.relativeId = relativeId;
    }
}
```

i hope this is enough to get some ideas, i would have liked to add a column just for the id but i think im not able to do that anymore.
Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to write init binder for idRelationship, isRelative and idPatient

Comment: Things would be a lot simpler if you used the `@IdClass` strategy instead of `@EmbeddedId`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps someone.
First , my `Patient_Relative` class  was short 1 variable , the one that would store the composite id, so i added the variable `PatientRelativeId compositeId`.

Second, at the controller method all i had to do was set the values of the composite id , the patient and the relative , and then call the service to create the object.

```
@RequestMapping(value="addPatientFamilyRelative",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String addPatientFamilyRelative(@RequestParam(value="idPatient")int idPatient,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="idRelative")int idRelative,
                                                             @RequestParam(value="idRelationship")int idRelationship)
    {
        Patient_Relative patientRelative = new Patient_Relative();
                PatientRelativeId id = new PatientRelativeId(idPatient, idRelative);
                patientRelative.setPatienRelativeId(id);
                patientRelative.setIdRelationship(relationshipService.getById(idRelationship));
                patientRelative.setPatient(patientService.getById(idPatient));
                patientRelative.setRelative(relativeService.getRelative(idRelative));


                prService.create(patientRelative);

        return "addRelative";
    }
```